# Issue with Tailwind CSS w-full

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Tailwind css w-full is not working in my case, not sure where is the issue exactly.

In the below code snippet, I am using CommandItemsSearch component in page.tsx and I used ShadCn UI Command Component and filling the data. Data filling is working without any issues, where as only design part has issues with w-full.

**page.tsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import NavBar from '@/components/NavBar'
import {
    ResizableHandle,
    ResizablePanel,
    ResizablePanelGroup,
} from "@/components/ui/resizable"
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"
import selectItems from './server-actions/selectItems'
import CommandItemsSearch from './components/CommandItemsSearch'
import { ItemDialog } from './components/ItemDialog'
import * as z from "zod"
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod"
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils"
import {
    Form,
    FormControl,
    FormDescription,
    FormField,
    FormItem,
    FormLabel,
    FormMessage,
} from "@/components/ui/form"
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form"
import { useToast } from '@/components/ui/use-toast'
import { useItemStore } from './store'
import { addItem } from "./server-actions/addItem"
import IngredientsPage from "../ingredients/page"
import InitItems from "./InitItems"


async function getItems() {
    const ItemsData = await selectItems()
    return ItemsData;
}

const ItemsPage = async () => {

    let itemsList = await getItems() || []

    return (
        <div className='flex-1 w-full flex-col items-center'>
            {/* <InitItems items={itemsList}/> */}
            <NavBar />
            <div className='flex justify-between mr-10 mt-5'>
                <h1 className='ml-10 font-bold text-3xl'>
                    Items
                </h1>
                <ItemDialog formType={"Add"} />
            </div>
            <div className='ml-10 mr-10 h-[calc(100vh_-_165px)]'>
                <ResizablePanelGroup
                    direction="horizontal"
                    className="rounded-lg border h-screen"
                >
                    <ResizablePanel defaultSize={25}>
                        <div className="flex h-full items-center justify-center bg-orange-300">
                            <span className="flex h-full w-full">
                                <CommandItemsSearch items={itemsList} />
                            </span>

                        </div>
                    </ResizablePanel>
                    {/* <ResizableHandle withHandle /> */}
                    <ResizableHandle />
                    <ResizablePanel defaultSize={75}>
                        <IngredientsPage />
                    </ResizablePanel>
                </ResizablePanelGroup>
                {/* <DataTable columns={columns} data={data} /> */}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ItemsPage




**CommandItemsSearch**
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import {
    Command,
    CommandEmpty,
    CommandGroup,
    CommandInput,
    CommandItem,
    CommandList,
    CommandSeparator,
    CommandShortcut,
} from "@/components/ui/command"
import {
    Calculator,
    Calendar,
    CreditCard,
    Settings,
    Smile,
    User,
} from "lucide-react"
import { Badge } from '@/components/ui/badge'
import { useItemStore } from '../store'


export default function CommandItemsSearch({ items }: { items: ty_Tbl_Items[] }) {
    const itemTypeList = [
        {
            value: "sale",
            label: "Sale",
            variant: 'bg-green-600 text-white',
        },
        {
            value: "rawmaterial",
            label: "Raw Material",
            variant: 'bg-blue-600 text-white'
        },
    ]

    async function onItemSelect(item: { item: ty_Tbl_Items }) {
        console.log(item)
    }

    const item = useItemStore((state) => state.item);
    const setItem = useItemStore((state) => state.setItem)
    const setItems = useItemStore((state) => state.setItem)


    const colorItemTypeVariants: any = {
        sale: 'bg-red-600 text-white',
        rawmaterial: 'bg-blue-600 text-white',
    }
    return (
        <div className='flex h-full bg-blue-300 w-full'>
            <Command>
                <CommandInput placeholder="Type a command or search..." />
                    <CommandList className='flex  bg-blue-300 items-start h-full'>
                        <CommandEmpty>No results found.</CommandEmpty>
                             <CommandGroup className='bg-red-300 flex-1'>
                                {
                                    items!.map(val => {
                                        const label = itemTypeList.find((label: any) => label.value === val.item_type)
                                        return <>
                                            <CommandItem className='justify-between' onSelect={(selected) => {
                                                setItem({ ...item, id: val.id })
                                                onItemSelect({ item: val } as { item: ty_Tbl_Items })
                                            }}>
                                                {val.item_name}
                                                <Badge variant="outline" className={`${colorItemTypeVariants[label!.value]}`}>{label!.label}</Badge>
                                            </CommandItem>
                                        </>
                                    })
                                }
                            </CommandGroup>
                    </CommandList>
            </Command>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Orange background div is not filled with parent width.

Comment: it would be better to share the vanilla html rendered if you want something easy to verify from people attempting to give an answer. Anyway if by saying _Orange background div is not filled with parent width_ you meant that elements `<CommandItem>` don't take the full available width constrained by their parent, it's maybe because their parent `<command>` isn't styled to take full width (`w-full`)

Comment: Consider that the command immediate parent is a flex container despite being set as `w-full`and its children don't just take the full available width if not set to